# Using <input type="slider">

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, semantics

Obviously, `<input type="slider">` doesn't exist in the spec, *however*, I want to use it as a placeholder/identifier for a plugin I'm writing.

This plugin will actually replace the `<input>` with a load of divs to make a slider similar to jQuery UI's control.

My question is; is using `<input type="slider">` simply as an identifier of where to place the jQuery-generated code generally "ok" - will it cause issues of any form, or do I need not worry?

Comment: It does exist in the spec, [it is called range](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#range-state)

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah I saw that, but I was referring specifically to `type="slider"`, not the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be OK since browsers render unknown input types as `<input type="text">`. See [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-email) for reference.

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, a better solution for this problem is probably to use `class="slider"` because that is guaranteed to never have any meaning besides the one you use it for, unlike `type="slider"` which some browser could potentially decide to render differently.

Comment: Just what I needed to hear - thanks. Also, I had a look at the HTML 5 spec and the closes you get is `<input type="range">`

Comment: I disagree. There are proper mechanisms to include non-spec content in your HTML, and hijacking the `type` attribute is not one of them.

Comment: @You I agree that this is not a good way of doing that, but it will not cause rendering or form problems, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: Valid HTML is a plus, but if using a custom type in an input **that will be replaced entirely anyway**, IMO it's fine to use custom types.

Comment: @JamWaffles The point is that it is probably better to use `<input class="slider">` because that is guaranteed to never have any semantic meaning to the browser, and in general it is better to not use attributes that have meanings besides the one you are using it for.

Comment: Ok murgatroid, I'll use a class instead of type. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 has this new option, it will only work in newer browsers.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Just use

```
data-whateveryouwanthere
```

JQuery has ways of manipulating this data also.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this wasn't exactly what I was asking. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @JamWaffles: This is what you *should* do (set `type="text"` and e.g. `data-type-override="slider"`, or for compatibility with older browsers maybe a `class="slider"` attribute). You can't simply hijack standard HTML attributes, that'll give you invalid markup.